# Latitude and Longitudes are replaced with zeros when importing excel 2007 worksheet into personal geodatabase

Tags: convert, coordinate-system, coordinates, personal-geodatabase

I am trying to import an Excel 2007 data set into a personal geodatabase so I can convert coordinate systems.  The data set includes point locations in Decimal Degrees. When I import the Excel worksheet, the latitude and longitudes in the resulting geodatabase table have been replaced with zeros.  Why is this?  This didn't occur with a different data set I have.

Thanks

Jason

Comment: Are the lat/lon fields in your XLS formatted as decimal numbers specifically?

Answer (score 2):

If your lat longs are expressed in the Excel sheet with non-numeric characters you'll need to convert them to straight decimal values for the import to work.